# Xamarin Forms Image is not showing on specific content page

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I'm working on xamarin forms PCL project and got stuck with a weird issue. I have a grid view and I'm trying to set the background of that grid, below is my code

```
<Grid BackgroundColor="White" RowSpacing="0">

<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="9*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<Grid x:Name="HeaderLayout" Grid.Row="0">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="6*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Image x:Name="headerImage" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Source="Header.png" Aspect="Fill"/>            
    <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="arrow_back.png" />
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="Login" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="Black"></Label>
    <Image Grid.Column="2" Source="setting.png"   />
</Grid>

<StackLayout x:Name="MainLayout" Grid.Row="1"/>

</Grid>
```

"***headerImage***" is my image for the grid background. I'm using the same layout on different other content pages. But, on some of the pages, the ***headerImage*** is not showing and on other pages its working fine. It's happening in android part. 
Any clue to the above weird behavior.

**Note: All images are in *resource/drawable* folder in Android and build Action is AndroidResource.**

***Edited***:  I've posted the solution below please refer, may help someone.

Comment: maybe some screenshots can help in better explaining ?

Comment: Aren't the pages in different folders? It shouldn't cause the problem, but just checking.

Comment: Can you show what are you trying to achieve with an image?

Comment: Please refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=vswin#local-images), "it should be a valid Android resource name (ie. only lowercase letters, numerals, the underscore, and the period are allowed).", please use `Source="header.png"` not `Source="Header.png"`

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below 2 solutions, both worked for me:

- reducing the size of my header image
- increasing heap size in manifest file *android:largeHeap="true"*

hope it might help someone.

Thanks.